# Javascript Gallery onmouseUp with "#" link without jumping to top of page

Tags: javascript, gallery, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I realize that this is probably an "old school" way of doing this, but I finally got my gallery to work with one exception. If the gallery is located lower on the page, the "#" link on the thumbnails causes the page to jump the top. Is there a better way to create this gallery?

http://pacmill.bigrigmedia.com/cms/portfolio-detail-test3.html

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a return false will usually stop the page from jumping to the top when clicking on a # link.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;"><img src="..." /></a>
```

For your problem, I would go with Shawn's solution and just use CSS.  So delete all of the links around the images and add this to your document:

```
<style> img{cursor:pointer;} #Display{cursor:auto;} </style>
```

The second entry (#Display) is to make sure your main image does not get the pointer cursor.  It would be better to just drop a class on each of your images and then assign the cursor to images with that class.  That would look like so:

```
<style> img.myImage{cursor:pointer;} </style>    
<img class="myImage" src="...">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using the anchor tag in order to get the hand icon on hover.  You could get the same effect by using CSS.

```
style="cursor: hand;"
```

This should create the same effect and avoid the problem of the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

I **strongly** suggest you to don't use an anchor tag for that. JavaScript events can be added to any DOM element, just like in:

```
<li class="click-to-expand">
  <img src="..." />
</li>
```

And also, as some users already replied, you can use CSS pointer property to indicate a possible user interaction when hovering the clickable interface item.

```
.click-to-expand{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Remember to keep it accessible by providing a valid URL to access the content in case it's necessary (no javascript fallback).